# openni kinect: build errors

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have problems installing openni_kinect stack. I can't install the openni drivers on my system. I meet the following errors in my 'make':

../../../../../Wrappers/OpenNI.jni/methods.inl:314: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
/bin/sh: javac: not found
make[3]: *** [../../../Bin/Release/org.OpenNI.jar] Error 127
make[2]: *** [Wrappers/OpenNI.java] Error 2
failed to execute: make PLATFORM=x86 -C ../Build > /home/yuanwei/drivers/openni/build/openni/Platform/Linux-x86/CreateRedist/Output/BuildOpenNI.txt
Building Failed!
make[1]: *** [installed] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/yuanwei/drivers/openni'
make: *** [openni_lib] Error 2

I've installed java sdk but these errors still stay. Any ideas how to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11158/openni-kinect:-build-errors/) by [ychua](https://answers.ros.org/users/1060/ychua/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-09-12**:
Use the electric install instructions: http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu. Then, do sudo apt-get install openni-kinect (I'm remember that package name off the top of my head; might be slightly wrong).

**Comment by [ychua](https://answers.ros.org/users/1060/ychua/) on 2011-09-11**:
my system is ubuntu 10.04,  kernel linux 2.6.32-33-generic-pae, GNOME 2.30.2. My hardware is Intel Core2 duo CPU E8400. Pre-built packages? How do I install the pre-built packages? any url that you can point me to?

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-09-09**:
We're going to need to know more about your system. What platform? What hardare? What versions? If you're on ubuntu, why not just install using the pre-built packages?

**Comment by [ychua](https://answers.ros.org/users/1060/ychua/) on 2011-09-08**:
I was following the instruction to install the openni_kinect stack. And this is the point where I'm stuck

hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers
cd drivers
make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Mac, Thanks for your kindness and suggestions. I've managed to resolve the problem. It seems that even though I've followed the java sdk installation instructions from the oracle website, the default java version is always openjdk.

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sun-java-community-team/sun-java6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

I did the above steps to install the java6-sdk. And the openni-kinect driver builds successfully now!

---

Originally posted by [ychua](https://answers.ros.org/users/1060/ychua/) with karma: 71 on 2011-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on 2017-02-27**:
Thanks! This worked!